# Рендеринг блоков карточек товаров, где лучше хранить данные SQL или JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, form, action

С помощью php я реализовал админку, где только пользователю с ролью админ доступен код - это форма создание карточки. И как лучше сделать, что бы при рендеринге карт они показывались всем пользователям кто зашел на сайт. Если JS, то думаю в этой форме отправлять данные в json файл и сохранять там и выполнять функцию чтения файла json и выполнять функцию рендеринга или же через php, где все данные будут хранится в бд на сервере? И еще для js в таком случае не понадобится сервер там nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

Сильно зависит от прочих условий задачи: кол-ва товаров и наличия фильтров на сайте. Если есть фильтры и товаров много - вывод будет фильтроваться бэкендом и удобнее хранить в БД. С другой стороны, нет проблем передавать результаты в json и рендерить на фронте. Вывод - требуется уточнение, что именно и зачем вы хотите сделать

Comment: Например добавить новый товар, поэтому после создания нового товара нужно вывести его на страницу

Comment: Это не уточняет условия. Вы можете это сделать любым из описанных вами способов. Выбор конкретного зависит от ориентировочной нагрузки, того, что вы планируете делать с данными, и структуры этих данных. Похоже, что у вас что-то совсем простое. Вывод - храните в БД